# Render partial webpage in WebForms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, partial-views

In MVC you can very easily render a partial view within another view using the `HTML.Partial("ViewName")` helper function. What is the method used to do the same thing within an ASP.NET WebForms application? What I want to do is have 2 webpages with (huge amounts of) content and then I want to display them on a third page in different tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usercontrol is the best way use partial view in web forms.